# hibernate named query(select)

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

We are using hibernate as an ORM in our project along with Spring framework. Today, I faced one issue where one named query (basically a select query) is giving inconsistent results when being called multiple times. Hit to this select query is not in a loop whereas it is from the front end. So, when i am performing a same operation multiple times from the front end, sometimes query is fetching the correct data from the DB but sometimes not.

Example:(Sample code)

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("select debitid from ABCMstrEntity where entitynum=: entitynum and isopen=:Y");

query.set(........);

..
List<Object[]> list = (List<Object[]>)query.list;
```

In first 4 attempts, i got correct data in the list object.
In my 5th attempt, i got empty list object although data was present in db for the provided inputs. When i checked it using db query logs at DB end, i found that, there was no hit at DB end for my 5th attempt. So it seems, something has gone wrong here.

I also checked for cache related settings in hibernate in my project but we are not caching query results in any of the cache regions. Also, there was no exception in the applications logs.

Please someone help me on this issue in analyzing and fixing it.

Comment: Please start by replacing the sample code with your real code, including the full named query and the code where you get and execute the named query. The details you have provided don't say much.

Comment: Could you let me know what part of code you want to know. The code which i mentioned is almost the same which is used in my project.Before using "query.list()", i am just setting the parametric variable of the query which is in this case is "entitynum".

Comment: Relevant part of entities, configuration and the part where you get and call the query would be a good start. The example in your question uses the query itself for query name with invalid placeholders, so I assume that it is not correct. Plus "..." is not a good way to show what you are doing. Post the code as it is instead, if it is sensitive simply rename the entities and fields and remove fields not relevant to the question.

Comment: This issue is resolved now. We are actually using sharded db's where mysql db is splitted in 4 shards and i found that code was not properly setting the shard reference before calling the "query" in the question.